# integrate projects using Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

Have a question related to **VC using Git**. So, basically I have **3 different projects**:

- masterproject_bash (written in bash)
- project_python  (written in python/R)
- subproject_html_php  (written in html/css/php)

All of them **interact with each other** to run an automated **pipeline**. 'masterproject_bash' starts everything and tells when to run 'project_python' and 'subproject_html_php' among other minor things. Because I have to collaborate with other people I started using **Git to make VC of all these 3 projects**, however I didn't find or been capable to set a proper integration of the project into a single VC git repo. I tried to use **git submodules**, but I got confused how to use submodules when updating only certain parts of the project and/or updating project from remote to local etc ..

My wish would be to have all **3 projects successfully integrated into a single Git repository** (a local accessed via internal IP, i.e 192.168.1.50:/myGitRepos), like this:

```sh
masterproject_bash/
├── project_python/
│   ├── aux/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── core/
│   ├── data/
│   ├── subproject_html_php/
│   │   ├── html/
│   │   ├── icons/
│   │   ├── img/
│   │   ├── README
│   │   ├── db_connection.php
│   │   └── index.php
│   ├── tests/
│   ├── README
│   └── main.py
├── ref_files/
├── README
└── run.sh
```

... and when somebody wanted to modify for example  python/R code, clone the repo, make changes to python and push again to the remote location.

I wanted to ask for advice in order to do this:

- so would you recommend to use git submodules?
- If so, how you would do it?
- just for the sick of my curiosity hehe, is there any other easy-to-use apart from git submodules?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why do you need submodules here?  Is there any reason you can't just have each project in a separate folder?

Comment: Well I'm not sure I need submodules I was only wondering ... because I do not know much about VC (I accept suggestions here hehehe). The reason because I want to be integrated is that everything is an entire pipeline built using different languages. So I would like to join everything, but keeping their parts controlled using VC

Comment: If you need the 3 different parts to exist independently (so for example, they can be integrated into other projects separately) then maybe submodules/subtrees, but if they are just pieces of one larger project, then keep it simple and make them separate directories. People needing to update any of them can clone the whole project and make their change on a branch or on your main line, and push back to you or you pull in their stuff.